# BTRFS: resolve bytenr to file path

Tags: btrfs

I have several errors on my BTRFS partition (SSD -> luks -> BTRFS):

```
btrfs check --check-data-csum -p --force /dev/mapper/sda3_crypt
...
mirror 0 bytenr 1337316519936 csum 850178701 expected csum 2442214357
mirror 1 bytenr 1337316519936 csum 850178701 expected csum 2442214357
mirror 1 bytenr 1337316524032 csum 3411875857 expected csum 208994536
```

I'd like to know which files are affected but there are no inodes given.

Is there a way to resolve the listed *bytenr* values to an actual file path?

Answer (score 4):

To resolve the *bytenr* use the following command:

```
btrfs inspect-internal logical-resolve <bytenr> <path>
```

where `<path>` should point to the BTRFS top-level subvolume to be able to list the affected files in all snapshots (one *bytenr* may be linked by a file that exists in several snapshots).

Example:

```
mkdir /mnt/btrfs-root
mount -t btrfs -o subvolid=5 /dev/sda2 /mnt/btrfs-root

btrfs inspect-internal logical-resolve 1337316519936 /mnt/btrfs-root

umount /mnt/btrfs-root && rmdir /mnt/btrfs-root
```

Please note: `subvolid=5` will mount the "BTRFS root" (or top-level subvolume). *A freshly created filesystem is also a subvolume, called top-level, internally has an id 5.* ([Kernel.org](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Manpage/btrfs-subvolume#SUBVOLUME_AND_SNAPSHOT))